# message line in modes

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

In visual mode, the message display seems fixed:

- `VISUAL`: it contains either the number of characters selected or the number of lines;
- `VISUAL LINE`: contains the number of lines;
- `VISUAL BLOCK`: contains the dimensions of the selected area (rows × columns).

*Can this be customized and how?*

My goal is to run analysis functions on the selected
text targeting mainly `VISUAL` mode: counting characters,
line widths etc. Of course, one could filter the selection
by running a function on it but I’d like the information
to be updated live and conveniently located in the message
line.

*EDIT*: [The code that handles the behavior in question](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/normal.c#L3775)
doesn’t appear to be configurable.

Comment: no it can't. If you want this, then you can try to do this using the statusline option

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. The starting point is `:h 'statusline'`. However, I must point you towards vim-airline and powerline plugins. They already do many related things. If not what you're looking for, their (complicated) code should give you hints regarding what you what to achieve.

Comment: The ``statusline`` help doesn’t mention visual modes nor does ``status-line``. I already have a highly customized statusline which nevertheless is only visible in normal and insert mode.

Comment: No, but it should point you to `%` syntax. From here, call a function. In that function, test the current mode and if you're in visual mode, then you can start counting what you find in `getline("'[", "']")`.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I was actually referring to the *message line* which doesn’t even have help item.